# Not able to generate json data after fetching rows by alias in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am fetching rows from two tables through JOIN and by using alias.but it's not creating json data after assigning rows to json array.

Here is code;

```
$personal = $db->prepare('select pd.Id,pd.FirstName,pd.MiddleName,pd.LastName,pd.Gender,pd.Location,pd.Email,bd.BookTitle,bd.BookGenre,bd.BookWriter,bd.BookDescription from personaldetails pd,bookdetails bd where pd.Id = bd.UserId ORDER BY pd.Id DESC');

$personal->execute();
$json_data=array();
$id;


foreach($personal as $row)//foreach loop  
{  

    $json_array['id']=$row['pd.Id'];  
    $json_array['FirstName']=$row['pd.FirstName'];  
    $json_array['MiddleName']=$row['pd.MiddleName'];  
    $json_array['LastName']=$row['pd.LastName']; 
    $json_array['Gender']=$row['pd.Gender']; 
    $json_array['Location']=$row['pd.Location']; 
    $json_array['Email']=$row['pd.Email']; 
    $json_array['Mobile']=$row['pd.Mobile'];
    $json_array['BookTtile']=$row['bd.BookTitle']; 
    $json_array['BookGenre']=$row['bd.BookGenre']; 
    $json_array['BookWriter']=$row['bd.BookWriter']; 
    $json_array['BookDescription']=$row['bd.BookDescription'];  

    //here pushing the values in to an array  
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);  
}  

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you forget to fatch data form your query result.

Use **[fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)** to fetch data and

```
$personal->execute();
$json_data=array();
 while ($row = $personal->fetch_assoc()) {// fetch data from query
     $json_array['id']=$row['Id']; // don't use table name before ID
    $json_array['FirstName']=$row['FirstName'];// don't use table name FirstName
...................
}
```

Comment: but it's duplicating the first table columns across json object.
is there any possibilities to prevent duplication i.e it's only show 1 row of 1st table and 2 rows of seconds table in json

Comment: example:  
i am getting this,
[{id:'1',name:'abc',BookTitle:"xyz",Bookgenre:'iu'],{id='1',name:'abc',BookTile:"uvw",BookGenre:'po'}]

i want this,
[{id:'1',name:'abc',BookTitle:"xyz",Bookgenre:'iu',BookTile:"uvw",BookGenre:'po'}]

Comment: Don't use while loop for that!! if you want only single value